# Nested Level SQL dependency tree using SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, smo

I'm using SQL SMO to build tree like sql management studio dependency tree in my windows application

```
Server srv = new Server();
var dependencyWalker = new DependencyWalker(srv);
var dependencyTree = dependencyWalker.DiscoverDependencies(new Urn[] { srv.Databases["myDB"].Tables["Resource"].Urn }, DependencyType.Parents);
var dependencyCollection = dependencyWalker.WalkDependencies(dependencyTree);
```

dependencyCollection is a flat linear list of 8 DependencyCollectionNode items, I can't figure any nested level dependency as shown in sql management studio dependency tree.

[image]

I need to get the first level items(Model, POP, Resource_Log, ResourceType) of my DB object(Resource)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dependencyTree.

The point of the DependencyWalker is to convert the tree to a linear list so that (for example) objects can be created in the correct order and not generate errors. It appears that you don't need this and you should just deal with the DependencyTree object directly.

Comment: You are right, I've to use the DependencyTreeNode FirstChild and NextSibling properties to start navigation, the problem is there are many circule references in the leaf level to the root level, which need a complex logic to avoid when binding.